# Next.js 14: How to Use a Reusable Button Component Inside a Server Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently working on a cool project using Next.js 14, and I'm facing a small hiccup. I've crafted a global and reusable button component with some nifty props like onClick and children. The catch? I'm trying to seamlessly use this button component within a page that's a "server component" by default.

Here's the snag: despite my efforts, I'm feeling a bit puzzled. Is it possible to utilize the button's onClick event inside a "server component" without slapping a "use client" on top of my page file? It seems like every attempt results in an error, and I'm scratching my head.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.
  <... onClick={function} children="Test">
               ^^^^^^^^^^
If you need interactivity, consider converting part of this to a Client Component.
```

Anyway, Here's My Code:

***Button***

```
"use client"
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes } from "react"

export default function Button({ onClick, children }: ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>) {

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>
        {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

***Page (index/root)***

```
import { Button } from '@/components'

export default function Home() {
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    console.log(111);
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <Button onClick={handleOnClick}>Test</Button>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Any insights, tips, or wizardry you can share to help me conquer this challenge? ‍♂️ Your wisdom is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the onclick handler with a createEffect?

const handleOnClick = createEffect(() => {
    console.log(111);
})

Comment: Define Button as server component.